# Proof verification: Construction of a perfect set of irrational numbers

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, real-numbers

I am trying to construct a perfect set of irrational numbers inductively, as follows.

Let $\{r_1,r_2,r_3, \ldots\}$ be an enumeration of the rational numbers $\mathbb{Q}.$

**Notation**:
For $x \in \mathbb{R}$, define

- $V_0(x)\colon= \emptyset,$ and
- $V_{\varepsilon}(x) \colon = \{y \in \mathbb{R}: |x-y|<\varepsilon\}=(x-\varepsilon, x+\varepsilon),$ for $\varepsilon>0$.

First choose $\varepsilon_1=\sqrt{2}>0.$ Then consider the set $U_1=V_{\varepsilon_1}(r_1).$ Now suppose that we have defined $\varepsilon_1, \ldots, \varepsilon_n\geq 0$ and set $U_n=\bigcup_{k=1}^{n}V_{\varepsilon_k}(r_k).$ We define $$\varepsilon_{n+1}=\frac{1}{2}\inf\left\{|r_{n+1}-x|: x \in U_n \right\}$$
and $U_{n+1}=U_n\cup V_{\varepsilon_{n+1}}(r_{n+1}).$

The infimum above always exists because $x_1 \in U_n$ and $0$ is a lower bound for the set $\{|r_{n+1}-x|:x \in U_n\}.$

Note that $\varepsilon_{n+1}$ is just the half of the distance from $r_{n+1}$ to the set $U_n.$

Now, set $U=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} U_n.$ Observe that $\mathbb{Q} \subseteq U.$ We want to show that $U^c$ is perfect. Since it is clearly closed, it only remains to show that $U^c$ has no isolated points. We will deduce that from some previous claims.

**Claim 1.** If $m,n \in \mathbb{N}$ are distinct, then $V_{\varepsilon_n}(r_n)\cap V_{\varepsilon_{m}}(r_m)=\emptyset.$

*Proof of claim 1.* If $\varepsilon_n=0$ or $\varepsilon_m=0$, the claim follows directly from the definition $V_0(x)=\emptyset.$ So we have only to consider the case where both $\varepsilon_n$ and $\varepsilon_m$ are positive. Withouth lost of generality, we may assume $m>n$.

If $y \in V_{\varepsilon_n}(r_n)\cap V_{\varepsilon_m}(r_m),$ then $y\in U_n$ and $|r_m-y|<\varepsilon_m.$ Since $m>n$, we have that $m-1\geq n,$ so that $U_{n} \subseteq U_{m-1},$ and hence $\{|r_m-x|:x\in U_n\}\subseteq \{|r_m-x|: x\in U_{m-1}\}.$ This, togheter with the fact that $y \in U_n$ allows us to deduce
$$\varepsilon_m<\inf\{|r_m-x|: x\in U_{m-1}\} \leq \inf \{|r_m-x|:x\in U_n\}\leq |r_m-y|<\varepsilon_m.$$ A contradiction.

This proves the Claim 1. $\blacksquare$

**Claim 2.** If $\varepsilon_n>0$ for some fixed $n \in \mathbb{N}$, then $r_n+\varepsilon_n, r_n-\varepsilon_n \notin U.$

*Proof of Claim 2.* First suppose by contradiction that $r_n+\varepsilon_n \in U.$ Then there is a $m \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $r_n+\varepsilon_n \in V_{\varepsilon_m}(r_m).$ It clearly cannot happen that $r_n+\varepsilon_n \in V_{\varepsilon_n}(r_n),$ thus $m\neq n$. Now, since $V_{\varepsilon_m}(r_m)$ is an open set containing $r_n+\varepsilon_n=\sup V_{\varepsilon_n}(r_n)$, then there is an $x\in V_{\varepsilon_{n}}(r_n)$ such that $x\in V_{\varepsilon_m}(r_m)$.  This contradicts the asserted in Claim 1 and hence, $r_n+\varepsilon_n \notin U.$

We can show in the same way that $r_n-\varepsilon_n \notin U.$ This furnishes the proof of Claim 2. $\blacksquare$

**Corollary 1.**  $U^c$ is nonempty and $r_n\pm \varepsilon_n$ are irrational whenever $\varepsilon_n>0$.

*Proof of Corollary 1.* By Claim 2, we deduce that $r_1+\varepsilon_1=r_1+\sqrt{2}\in U^c$ and then $U^c$ is nonempty.

If $\varepsilon_n>0$ and $r_n\pm \varepsilon_n$ is rational, then $r_n\pm \varepsilon_n \in U,$ by construction. This contradicts the Claim 2. $\blacksquare$

**Claim 3.** If $\varepsilon_m=0$ for some fixed $m\geq 2$, then $r_m\in U_{m-1}.$

*Proof of Claim 3.* In order to get a contradiction, suppose that $r_m \notin U_{m-1}.$ Then  for each $1\leq k \leq m-1,$ we have that $r_m \leq r_k-\varepsilon_k$ or $r_k+\varepsilon_k \leq r_m.$ Since $r_m$ is rational and $r_k \pm \varepsilon_k$ isn't, then the equalities cannot hold and then, for each $k \in \{1, \ldots, m-1\},$ we should have $r_m < r_k-\varepsilon_k$ or $r_k+\varepsilon_k < r_m.$ This shows that
$$r_m \in  I=\bigcap_{k=1}^{m-1} \left[ (-\infty, r_k-\varepsilon_k)\cup (r_k+\varepsilon_k, \infty)\right].$$

Since $I$ is open as being finite intersection of open sets, there exists $\delta>0$ such that $V_\delta(r_m) \subseteq I$. Finally, if $x \in U_{m-1},$ then $x \notin I,$ and hence, $x \notin V_\delta(r_m).$ It follows that $|r_m-x| \geq \delta>0.$ We conclude that $\delta$ is a positive lower bound of the set $\{|r_m-x|: x \in U_{m-1}\}.$ This is imposible, since the infimum of this set (i.e. $\varepsilon_m$) is zero.

Then, $r_m \in U_{m-1}.$ $\blacksquare$

**Claim 4.** If $r_n<r_l$ and $\varepsilon_n, \varepsilon_l>0$ for fixed $n,l \in \mathbb{N},$ then $r_n+\varepsilon_n<r_l-\varepsilon_l.$

*Proof of Claim 4.*

Case 1. $r_l-\varepsilon_l<r_n+\varepsilon_n.$ Choose $s=\max\{r_l-\varepsilon_l, r_n-\varepsilon_n\}.$ By our hypotesis, we have $s<r_n+\varepsilon_n.$ Also, $s<r_l+\varepsilon_l$ because clearly $r_l-\varepsilon_l<r_l+\varepsilon_l$ and $r_n-\varepsilon_n<r_n<r_l<r_l+\varepsilon_l$. In consequence, $m=\min\{r_n+\varepsilon_n, r_l+\varepsilon_l\}>s.$ Choose any $x \in (s,m).$ Then $x \in V_{\varepsilon_n}(r_n)\cap V_{\varepsilon_l}(r_l).$  This contradicts what we proven on Claim 1 (it should be clear that $n\neq l$). This case is impossible.

Case 2. $r_l-\varepsilon_l=r_n+\varepsilon_n.$ Suppose first that $n>l.$ Then $V_{\varepsilon_l}(r_l)\subseteq U_{n-1}.$ Observe that $r_n\leq r_l-\varepsilon_l,$ because if not, $r_l-\varepsilon_l<r_n<r_l<r_l+\varepsilon_l $, and then we would have $r_n\in V_{\varepsilon_l}(r_l)\subseteq U_{n-1},$ and hence $\varepsilon_n=0,$ a contradiction. Furthermore, $r_n<r_l-\varepsilon_l$ because $r_l-\varepsilon_l \notin U$ according to Claim   2. This implies that $r_l-\varepsilon_l-r_n=\inf\{|r_n-x|:x \in V_{\varepsilon_l}(r_l)\}.$ Furthermore, since $\{|r_n-x|:x \in V_{\varepsilon_l}(r_l)\}\subseteq \{|r_n-x|:x \in U_{n-1}\},$ we have
$$0<\varepsilon_n<\inf\{|r_n-x|:x \in U_{n-1}\}\leq \inf\{|r_n-x|:x \in V_{\varepsilon_l}(r_l)\}=r_l-\varepsilon_l-r_n.$$

Then $\varepsilon_n+r_n<r_l-\varepsilon_l.$ A similar argument shows that if $n<l,$ then $\varepsilon_n+r_n\neq r_l-\varepsilon_l.$

We conclude that this case is also impossible.

The only remaining case is actually what we wanted to show. This ends the proof of Claim 4. $\blacksquare$

**Claim.** The set $U^c$ has no isolated points.

*Proof.* Let $\alpha \in U^c$ and $\varepsilon>0.$ Choose a rational point $r_m\in (\alpha-\varepsilon, \alpha).$

If $\varepsilon_m>0,$ then $r_m+\varepsilon_m \leq \alpha,$ otherwise, $r_m-\varepsilon_m<r_m<\alpha<r_m+\varepsilon_m$ and hence $\alpha \in V_{\varepsilon_m}(r_m) \subseteq U,$ a contradiction. Then, we can find an $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $ r_n+\varepsilon_n \in (\alpha-\varepsilon, \alpha].$

If $\varepsilon_m=0,$ then $r_m \in U_{m-1},$ by Claim 3. Then $r_m \in V_{\varepsilon_n}(r_n)$ for some $n\leq m-1.$ Since $V_{\varepsilon_n}(r_n)$ is nonempty, then $\varepsilon_n>0.$ Observe that $r_n+\varepsilon_n \leq \alpha,$ because if not, we would have $r_n-\varepsilon_n<r_m<\alpha<r_n+\varepsilon_n,$ and hence $\alpha \in V_{\varepsilon_n}(r_n)\subseteq U.$ Observe that $\alpha-\varepsilon<r_m<r_n+\varepsilon_n \leq \alpha,$ and then $r_n+\varepsilon_n \in (\alpha-\varepsilon, \alpha].$

In any case, we can find $n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $ r_n+\varepsilon_n \in (\alpha-\varepsilon, \alpha]$ and $\varepsilon_n>0.$

We can repeat the process above to find $l\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $ r_l-\varepsilon_l \in [\alpha, \alpha+\varepsilon)$ and $\varepsilon_l>0.$

Since $\varepsilon_n>0,$ it follows from Claim 2 that $r_n+\varepsilon_n \notin U.$ So, if $r_n+\varepsilon_n<\alpha,$ then we have found an element of $U^c$ (namely, $r_n+\varepsilon_n$) distinct from $\alpha$ and contained in $(\alpha-\varepsilon, \alpha+\varepsilon)=V_\varepsilon(\alpha).$ Now, what if $r_n+\varepsilon_n=\alpha?$ Then using the fact that $\varepsilon_n, \varepsilon_l>0$ and $r_n<r_l$ togheter with the Claim 4 we conclude that $r_l-\varepsilon_l>\alpha$ and hence $r_l-\varepsilon_l \in (\alpha, \alpha+\varepsilon).$  Then, again we have found an element of $U^c$ (namely, $r_l-\varepsilon_l$) distinct from $\alpha$ that is contained in $V_\varepsilon(\alpha).$ This finishes the proof. $\blacksquare$

Thanks in advance if you read until the finish of the proof. Does this long proof seems ok to you? I hope you can help me with this.